# Strange result when sorting files in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I get a strange result when sorting files in bash

```
ruediger@r30-pc-2:~/myPics$ ls
'Picture 001b.jpg'  'Picture 011.jpg'  'Picture 024.jpg'   'Picture 032.jpg'
'Picture 001c.jpg'  'Picture 013.jpg'  'Picture 027.jpg'   'Picture 033.jpg'
'Picture 001.jpg'   'Picture 014.jpg'  'Picture 028.jpg'   'Picture 034.jpg'
'Picture 003a.jpg'  'Picture 015.jpg'  'Picture 028r.jpg'  'Picture 038a.jpg'
'Picture 003b.jpg'  'Picture 016.jpg'  'Picture 028s.jpg'  'Picture 038.jpg'
'Picture 003.jpg'   'Picture 018.jpg'  'Picture 029a.jpg'  'Picture 039.jpg'
'Picture 009.jpg'   'Picture 019.jpg'  'Picture 029b.jpg'  'Picture 040.jpg'
'Picture 010.jpg'
```

Normally index `001` should be before `001b` and `001c` (same for `003`, `003a`, `003b`).
I tried to pipe `ls | sort` with different options, but the result remains the same.

Interesting to see, that pictures with index `028`, `028r`, `028s` were sorted correctly. I played around with the indices `001` and followings and found out that beginning with `001k` it was sorted correctly.

I tried string comparison in bash:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ "Picture 001" < "Picture 001b" ]]
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

results in `true`. but putting the same suffix behind both strings (like `.jpg` or `.txt`) results  in `false`.

I don't understand this sorting algorithm and to be honest, it seems to have a bug. Other programs sort this correctly.

Comment: show your `locale` output

Comment: Could you run the command `ls | od -x` and post result ?

Comment: The result is too long to post it here. Here is a part if it helps:
0000740 6369 7574 6572 3020 3033 6a2e 6770 500a
0000760 6369 7574 6572 3020 3133 6a2e 6770 500a
0001000 6369 7574 6572 3020 3233 6a2e 6770 500a
0001020 6369 7574 6572 3020 3333 6a2e 6770 500a
0001040 6369 7574 6572 3020 3433 6a2e 6770 500a
0001060 6369 7574 6572 3020 3833 2e61 706a 0a67
0001100 6950 7463 7275 2065 3330 2e38 706a 0a67
0001120 6950 7463 7275 2065 3330 2e39 706a 0a67
0001140 6950 7463 7275 2065 3430 2e30 706a 0a67
0001160 6950 7463 7275 2065 3430 2e33 706a 0a67
0001200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```bash
printf '%s\n' Picture*.jpg | LANG=C sort
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. I didn't know that it's possible to work with C in BASH. My Problem: I'm not very familiar with C. Is there any other solution with BASH-commands?

Comment: @R.30 You already got a pure POSIX shell solution here, `LANG=C` doesn't have anything to do with the `C` language, it sets locale the `sort` command (any sorting is sensitive to the locale). You can also use `LANG=C ls`, or `export LANG=C; printf '%s\n' *`

Comment: Works. I put ```LANG=C``` in the beginning of the shell script and got correct results.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works too, when the suffix of files can be ignored (what it does in my case):

`ls | sort -t . -k 1,1`